# Do you know to correctly refrencing "this" for jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have this a jqgrid like this:

```
$("#MyTable").jqGrid({
        height: 600,
        url: 'list.json',
        colNames: ColN,
        colModel: Colm,
        sortable: true,
        multiselect: true,
loadComplete: function() {

getEditPage('#MyTable');

}
});
```

getEditPage function is:

```
function getEditPage(tableId,objectType){
    var ids = $(tableId).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        var idList = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        idList = idList + ids[i] + " ";
        }

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        $('#'+ids[i]+' a').click(function(e) {editClickEvent(e, tableId, objectType, idList);});
    }
    if ($(tableId + '_forzen')) {
            $(tableId + '_frozen tr').slice(1).each(
                    function() {
                        $('td', this).each(
                                function() {
                                    $('a', this).click(function(e) {editClickEvent(e, tableId, objectType, idList);});
                                }
                        );
                    });
       }
};
```

Here is editClickEvent:

```
var editClickEvent = function(e, tableId, objectType, idList) {
    $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
    var myHash = e.currentTarget.hash;     // string like "#?id=0"
    var id = myHash.substring(5, myHash.length); // getting row Id
    if (id.indexOf("&") >=0) {
        id = id.substring(0, id.indexOf("&"));
    }
    if (myHash.substring(0,5) === '#?id=') {
        var rowData = $(tableId).jqGrid('getRowData', id);
        var param = myHash.substring(myHash.length-1);
        if (objectType) {
            param = objectType;
        }
        if(param == 'D'){
            var cellValue = this.textContent || this.innerText;
            if((cellValue.search('\n') != 0)&&(cellValue.lastIndexOf('\n')==cellValue.indexOf('\n')))        {
                var m_Id = rowData.id;
                var m_Id = m_Id.substring(0,m_Id.length-1);
                var url = 'path';
                hasPermissionByIds('M', m_Id, 1, gotoPage, url);
            } else if(cellValue.search('\n') != 0){
                var cellValueArray = makeArray2(cellValue);
                var cellIdsArray = makeArray2(rowData.id);
                createPromtDialog(cellValueArray, cellIdsArray, param);                                 
            }
e.preventDefault();
};
```

The issue is in the `var cellValue = this.textContent || this.innerText;` . textContent and innerText is undefined. I know it is the issue of "this" which is referenced wrong. Do you have any idea that I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the call of functions `editClickEvent` and `getEditPage` so that it forward the value of `this` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)). For example

```
$('#'+ids[i]+' a').click(function(e) {editClickEvent.call(this, e, ...
```

instead of

```
$('#'+ids[i]+' a').click(function(e) {editClickEvent(e,
```

or

```
getEditPage.call(this, '#MyTable');
```

instead of

```
getEditPage('#MyTable');
```

By the way after usage `.call` you can modify code of `getEditPage` to get the value of `id` of the table from `tableId`: `this.id` will be `"MyTable"`. So `"#" + this.id` is equal to `"#MyTable"`.